# Update query multiple joins from MS Access to Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, ms-access, sql-update, inner-join

I am clue less about this syntax which is working fine in **MS Access**

```
UPDATE (Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON (Table1.IDENT = Table2.IDENT) AND (Table1.AREA = Table2.AREA)) 
INNER JOIN Table3 ON (Table2.IDENT = Table3.IDENT) AND (Table2.AREA = Table3.AREA) 
SET Table3.ELEV = Table2.elev, Table3.NAME = Table2.name, Table3.CYCLE = "1807";
```

I am looking for Oracle equivalent of this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)

Comment: Negative, In this query UPDATE's target is an uknown alias. SET statement is on actual table. That is causing confusion,

Comment: Plus, I do not see any  SELECT in this version of query

Comment: Did you read the other link properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this, perhaps?

```
UPDATE table3 t3
   SET (t3.elev, t3.name, t3.cycle) =
          (SELECT t2.elev, t2.name, '1807'
             FROM table2 t2
                  JOIN table1 t1
                     ON     t1.ident = t2.ident
                        AND t1.area = t2.area
            WHERE     t2.ident = t3.ident
                  AND t2.area = t3.area);
```

Comment: I'm glad if it is :)