# Oracle update sql query

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update, query-performance

My query is this. It is not showing error. But having a long execution time that Iam forced to close. Please check

```
update trans_rec a
set a.qty = (select b.qtydes from itbg_store_delchellan b where b.icode = 
a.icode and a.controlno=b.DEL_NO AND A.controlno IS NOT NULL) 
where exists 
    (select b.qtydes from itbg_store_delchellan b where b.icode = a.icode and 
    a.controlno=b.DEL_NO  AND A.controlno IS NOT NULL )
```

Comment: add some indexes

Comment: put in main where this condition A.controlno IS NOT NULL

Comment: What is the size of data?  It may be in execution.

Comment: @Zeki's below answer seems the way to go: an update based on a query with a join.

Comment: if you could put query plan may be we could give better answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use a `MERGE` statement in Oracle.

```
MERGE INTO trans_rec t USING 
( select DISTINCT icode,del_no,qtydes
       FROM itbg_store_delchellan s 
)
ON (
     s.icode = t.icode AND t.controlno = s.del_no
)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.qty = s.qtydes
WHERE t.controlno IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: ORA-30926: unable to get a stable set of rows in the source tables

Comment: @user3698150 : That's because you have multiple values in `itbg_store_delchellan` for that key. I have added a `DISTINCT` now. please check.

Answer (score 1):

You can re-write your query as follow:

```
UPDATE trans_rec a
SET a.qty =
    (SELECT b.qtydes 
    FROM itbg_store_delchellan b
    WHERE b.icode = a.icode and a.controlno=b.DEL_NO) 
WHERE a.controlno IS NOT NULL
AND EXISTS
(SELECT b.qtydes FROM itbg_store_delchellan b
WHERE b.icode = a.icode AND a.controlno=b.DEL_NO)
```

After this you must add indexes on your field search, as follow:

add following filter on these fields

- b.icode
- a.controlno
- a.icode

Answer (score 0):

Try this update:

```
UPDATE A
SET     qty = B.qtydes 
from    trans_rec AS A
INNER JOIN itbg_store_delchellan B
             ON B.icode = A.icode 
             AND A.controlno=b.DEL_NO 
             AND A.controlno IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: The advantage of this (in addition to being simple and fast) is that you can easily test what the update is going to do: replace the UPDATE and SET with a SELECT. `SELECT A.qty, B.qtydes new_qty
from    trans_rec AS A
INNER JOIN itbg_store_delchellan B
             ON B.icode = A.icode 
             AND A.controlno=b.DEL_NO 
             AND A.controlno IS NOT NULL `

Comment: You may want to check this post then: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2446834/6996150

Comment: Zeki Gumus: It is showing SQL querry not ended properly

Comment: This query won't work on Oracle, since Oracle does not support this syntax `update ... from ... join ...`.

Comment: I am sorry for confusing all. This query based on sql-server. I have missed to check the database provided on question. I already up-voted Joe Taras's answer which is I would offer same thing.

Answer (score 0):

To improve performance, create a composite index on `itbg_store_delchellan`:

```
create index idx_itbg_store_delchellan_3 on itbg_store_delchellan(icode, del_no, qtydes)
```

Note that the condition `A.controlno IS NOT NULL` is redundant.  The correlation condition will already filter out `NULL` values, so you can remove this from both subqueries.