# Oracle SQL : UPDATE JOIN

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-update

I'm trying to make an update query with a join statement. however, it keeps throwing an error of syntax I'm not really sure where am I going wrong here cause I think I have done it right.

```
UPDATE AlfaGood 
SET ag.name = 'New text goes here' 
FROM AlfaGood ag 
INNER JOIN SecondAlfa ca ON ca.id = 1 
                         AND ag.agrid = 'Thats my original text';
```

Please advise on the above if possible. I get an error

> ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended

saying it's missing `(; | ,)` before `FROM`

Comment: Replace `UPDATE AlfaGood` with `UPDATE ag`.

Comment: *"missing (; | ,) before FROM"*? That isn't a SQL Server error. SQL Server doesn't use Pipes (`|`).

Comment: Oracle SQL Developer is an IDE, not an RDBMS. I've corrected the tags for now what we have found out what is really the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: Update statement with joins are pretty much incomprehensible on Oracle, better off using a cursor or client side code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2446764/3484879)

Comment: Alright ... so I better update it manually! Thank you for your advice. I was wondering why not working cause I made this on normal SQL server so many times but in this job, I'm using Oracle SQL Dev

Comment: For future reference, Oracle UPDATE syntax is described here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/UPDATE.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
UPDATE AlfaGood ag
   SET ag.name = 'New text goes here' 
--FROM AlfaGood ag -- not an Oracle syntax
 WHERE ag.agrid = 'Thats my original text' 
   AND ag.id = 1 
   AND EXISTS ( SELECT ca.id FROM SecondAlfa ca WHERE ca.id = 1 );
```

Comment: please mark it as answer so it will help future readers like click on tick and make it green :)

Comment: I have now sorry if I was off past few days