# Update with join in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I've go this request in SQL for a migration:

```
UPDATE table1
SET table1.value = table2.value
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table2.othervalue2 = table1.key
WHERE table2.othervalue3 is NULL
```

Works well.
But not with Oracle. I know it isn't impossible to make join in a update with oracle, so I use this:

```
UPDATE table1 SET table1.value = (SELECT table2.value
                                  FROM table2
                                  WHERE table2.othervalue2 = table1.key
                                  AND table2.othervalue3 is NULL)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT table2.value
                                  FROM table2
                                  WHERE table2.othervalue2 = table1.key
                                  AND table2.othervalue3 is NULL)
```

but I have an ORA-01427: Subquery returns more than one row.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update statement with inner join on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446764/update-statement-with-inner-join-on-oracle)

Comment: yes I use this answer initially
For the second, I have an ORA-01779

Comment: Which answer? There are at least two different approaches in answers: with `update ... exists` and with `merge`

Comment: The first one.

For the approach with MERGE, I have an ORA-3029

`MERGE table1
USING table2
ON table2.othervalue2 = table1.key
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET table1.value = table2.value
WHERE table2.othervalue2 is NULL;`

Comment: Then please check [error messages](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/errmg/ORA-29250.html#GUID-DCC3FD1C-7487-469D-99AC-074BD4EAED94) and refine join condition to remove duplicates per join key. **Cause**: *A stable set of rows could not be got because of large dml activity or a non-deterministic where clause.* **Action**: *Remove any non-deterministic where clauses and reissue the dml.*

Answer (score 0):

i would say you have inconsistent data. From the Errors you get i would say you have duplicates in the query specified.

```
SELECT table2.value
  FROM table2
  WHERE table2.othervalue2 = table1.key
    AND table2.othervalue3 is NULL
```

you might wanne check it.or you need to have the data better specified you want to select for Update/Merge.