# MySQL: Updating values of "children" from their "parents"

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with rows of "parents" and "children". Similar entries, but one entry is generic version of the more specific child. However, I want these entries to match exactly in certain columns.

Here's an example of my database:

```
| ID |  IsChildOfID |   Food    |   Type        |
| 1  |              |           |   Fruit       |
| 2  |      1       |   Apple   |   Fruit       |
| 3  |      1       |   Pear    |   Vegetable   |
| 4  |      1       |   Banana  |   Vegetable   |
| 5  |              |           |   Vegetable   |
| 6  |      5       |   Lettuce |   Fruit       |
| 7  |      5       |   Celery  |   Vegetable   |
| 8  |      5       |   Cabbage |   Fruit       |
```

In this example there are 2 parents and 6 children. The value of "type" field is inconstant with some of the children. I want to be able to find any children in the database and replace it with their parent's value **in only some of the columns**. Is this possible with purely MySQL or do I need do it with php? Thanks.

Comment: what the hell is your profile pic, dude?

Comment: I think that it is a monkey ass... But please stay on the topic :)

Answer (score 1):

Generally, when you use parent/children relationships in sql, you should make two separate database tables for each. In your case, you should create a database entitled "types" and include a `type_id` for each element in the child table.

*Example*

**Child table:**

```
| ID |    TYPE_ID   |   Food    |
| 2  |      1       |   Apple   | 
| 3  |      2       |   Pear    |  
| 4  |      2       |   Banana  |   
| 6  |      1       |   Lettuce |  
| 7  |      2       |   Celery  | 
| 8  |      1       |   Cabbage |
```

**Type table:**

```
| ID |        Type          |
| 1  |        Fruit         |
| 2  |       Vegetable      |
```

You can then reference it by looping through the type table, and using a sql statement like

```
$types = mysql_query ( 'SELECT * FROM type_table');

WHILE ( $type = mysql_fetch_array ( $types ) )
{
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM  child_table WHERE TYPE_ID = "' . $type['type'] . '"';
}
```

Comment: Currently my database has around 20,000 entries. The "parents" have a lot of the same information as the children, with a couple exceptions. Would it be faster to split the database in 2 and have the children looked up, then look up their parents? Or is this for purely organizational purposes?

Comment: It is primarily for organization. You have two different data types, so you should have two different tables for them. But if you have that many entries already and only are trying to maintain them, then you should use some PHP/sql to update it. Dusan's answer might work

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE name_of_table SET Type = "Fruit" WHERE IsChildOfID = 1
```

and

```
UPDATE name_of_table SET Type = "Vegetable" WHERE IsChildOfID = 5
```

- But if you want to do it dynamicaly please use php or some other language...

Also I would prefer to use 2 tables for this kind of data...

Comment: OK since you're the second person to say I need to split the tables in two I'll do it. Much simplier than what I'm trying to ask.

Comment: @DusanRadojevic Good advice, I always hate doing self joins on tables, kinda takes the "relation" out of a "relational database" :-)

Comment: I decided not to do it actually, it over complicated the whole process splitting everything up.

Comment: I am repeating this in a lot of my comments, please consider what is good for you on a long term basis...

Answer (score 0):

Similar answer here:
[UPDATE multiple tables in MySQL using LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806882/update-multiple-tables-in-mysql-using-left-join)

I was going to write this:

```
UPDATE foods c
  JOIN foods p ON p.id = c.IsChildOfId 
   SET c.type = p.type
 WHERE p.isChildOfId IS NULL
```

But then upon further reading of the link above, not sure you can reference the target table.  Worth a try.