# You can't specify target table XXX for update in FROM clause (with SUM in subclause)

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, self-join, mysql-error-1093

I'm trying to execute this query:

```
        UPDATE  
            arc_salon_credit_exposant AS asce
        SET  
            asce.asce_credit_restant = 
                (
                    SELECT 
                        SUM(asce_credit_restant) 
                    FROM
                        arc_salon_credit_exposant
                    WHERE
                        asce_scre_id = '524' AND
                        asce_sexp_id = '719' AND
                        (asce_fam_id is NULL OR
                            asce_fam_id = '168')
                )
        WHERE  
            asce.asce_scre_id = '524' AND
            asce.asce_sexp_id = '719' AND
            asce.asce_fam_id is NULL
```

but, all I get is a mysql error (#1093 - You can't specify target table 'asce' for update in FROM clause). I've read some questions here at stackoverflow (that's why I tried using an alias), but I can't make it work. I know I have to write the query so Mysql will create a temp table, but.. I can't get this done. Kinda stuck here.

Here's the structure of the table:

```
Column name Type    Null    Défaut
asce_id int(11) Non 
asce_scre_id    int(11) Non 
asce_sexp_id    int(11) Non 
asce_credit_restant double  Oui NULL
asce_fam_id int(11) Oui NULL
```

And here's some data:

asce_id asce_scre_id    asce_sexp_id    asce_credit_restant asce_fam_id

35  524           7885           4900                   NULL

17  524            719            200                   NULL

45  524            719            100                   168

44  524           7885            100                   168

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your table [with](https://stackoverflow.com/a/806925/1369235) [join](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) like this one

```
UPDATE  arc_salon_credit_exposant AS asce
JOIN
(     SELECT 
         asce_credit_restant.IDColumn  --<<here your Unique column for self join
         SUM(asce_credit_restant) as tot
      FROM
         arc_salon_credit_exposant
      WHERE
         asce_scre_id = '524' AND
         asce_sexp_id = '719' AND
         asce_fam_id is NULL
) A
ON asce.IDColumn = A.IDColumn
SET asce.asce_credit_restant = A.tot
WHERE  
    asce.asce_scre_id = '524' AND
    asce.asce_sexp_id = '719' AND
    asce.asce_fam_id is NULL
```

#### [See this example demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/675b5)

Comment: thanks for your help, @hims056... sadly, I still have Mysql errors :( I can't have this query working - even after doing these changes You suggested.

Comment: @user1453418 - Can you show the data structure and sample data?