# Sql Update with Join statement

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables : first one stores main informations and the second stores some extra informations. I need to update the first table with the help of some data stored at second table.

My SELECT statement is working

```
SELECT  news.news_id, 
        news.title, 
        news.cat_id, 
        news.sub_cat_id, 
        news_extra.date_vision_tr
FROM news_extra
    JOIN news 
        ON news.news_id = news_extra.news_id
WHERE news.cat_id=1 AND sub_cat_id=5 AND news_extra.date_vision_tr < CURDATE()
```

Than I tried UPDATE statement like this

```
UPDATE news SET news.sub_cat_id=8 
FROM news
   INNER JOIN news_extra
        ON news.news_id = news_extra.news_id
WHERE news.cat_id=1 AND sub_cat_id=5 AND news_extra.date_vision_tr < CURDATE()
```

But its not working. Giving this error

> *You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'FROM news INNER JOIN news_extra ON news.news_id =
>   news_extra.news_id WHERE news.' at line 2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you are using is for `SQL Server`.

Here is the syntax for `MySQL`

```
UPDATE  news a
        INNER JOIN news_extra b
            ON a.news_id = b.news_id
SET     a.sub_cat_id = 8 
WHERE   a.cat_id = 1 and 
        sub_cat_id = 5 and 
        b.date_vision_tr < CURDATE()
```

Answer (score 0):

You must be familiar with SQL Server more. The syntax you are using will work in SQLServer. For MySQL:

```
UPDATE news
INNER JOIN news_extra
ON news.news_id = news_extra.news_id
SET news.sub_cat_id=8 
WHERE news.cat_id=1 and sub_cat_id=5 and news_extra.date_vision_tr < CURDATE()
```

--Try this way.

[Check similar thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806882/update-multiple-tables-in-mysql-using-left-join)