# Adding SQL Case to provide a default in an Update Query

Tags: mysql, join, sql-update, case

I am working on a query that will assign users to a specific building based on their lat/long coordinates.  The query does work and assigns a building id value to the associated user but I would like to assign a value of "unknown location" if no building exists at the users current location.

Essentially, IF location known SET u.building_id = b.building_id, ELSE SET u.building_id = 'unknown location';

The current query is as follows:

```
UPDATE USERS u 
JOIN BUILDINGS b ON u.latitude BETWEEN (b.latitude - 0.001) AND (b.latitude + 0.001)
    AND u.longitude BETWEEN (b.longitude - 0.001) AND (b.longitude + 0.001)
SET u.building_id = b.building_id
```

I am thinking this could be accomplished by adding an SQL cases?  How should I approach this?

Comment: Change made.  Sorry 'bout that ha

Answer (score 1):

You could use `CASE` like so, with a [`LEFT JOIN`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/806882/314291)

```
UPDATE USERS u
LEFT JOIN BUILDINGS b 
  ON u.latitude BETWEEN (b.latitude - 0.001) AND (b.latitude + 0.001)
  AND u.longitude BETWEEN (b.longitude - 0.001) AND (b.longitude + 0.001)
SET u.building_id = 
    CASE 
       WHEN b.building_id IS NULL THEN 'unknown location'
       ELSE b.building_id
    END;
```

Although personally I would use `COALESCE` to do the same thing:

```
UPDATE USERS u
LEFT JOIN BUILDINGS b 
     ON u.latitude BETWEEN (b.latitude - 0.001) AND (b.latitude + 0.001)
     AND u.longitude BETWEEN (b.longitude - 0.001) AND (b.longitude + 0.001)
SET u.building_id = COALESCE(b.building_id, 'unknown location');
```

Replacing the `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT JOIN` will ensure that all users are updated, including those with no matched building (hence the `NULL building_id`). Noted that if there is more than one match on the lat / long, that the assignment of building will be fairly arbitrary.

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a8b801/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE USERS u JOIN BUILDINGS b ON u.latitude BETWEEN (b.latitude - 0.001) AND (b.latitude + 0.001)
AND
u.longitude BETWEEN (b.longitude - 0.001) AND (b.longitude + 0.001)
SET u.building_id = (case when **location known** then u.building_id = b.building_id ELSE u.building_id = 'unknown location' END)
```

obviously you need to change **location known** for a logical expression

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE USERS u LEFT JOIN BUILDINGS b ON u.latitude BETWEEN (b.latitude - 0.001) AND (b.latitude + 0.001)
AND
u.longitude BETWEEN (b.longitude - 0.001) AND (b.longitude + 0.001)
SET u.building_id = IF( ISNULL(b.building_id), 'unknown', b.building_id);
```