# mysql display field values from subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery, field

I have following query that works correctly:

```
select * from myTable a where a.company is null and exists (select b.company from myTable b where b.id = a.id and b.office_id = a.office_id and b.company is not null);
```

Now, I also want to display the field value **b.company** from the subquery next to the fields from **myTable a**.

How do I get this done?

Thank you and best regards

Comment: use a an outer join instead of an exists check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want results from multiple tables you should join the tables together. 
Since you want only records from A that exist in B, you need to use an outer JOIN returning all records from A and only those matching in B.  But then you want to exclude all those records from A that were not found in B.

```
SELECT *, b.company
FROM  myTable a 
LEFT JOIN myTable B 
  ON b.id = a.id 
 and b.office_id = a.office_id
 and b.company_ID is not null
WHERE a.company is null 
  and B.ID is not null and B.office_ID is not null --this handles the exists part.
```

Comment: Wow I was off on joins a few times... should be correct now.

Comment: okay, this works very good. but how do I update 

a.company to value of b.company

with this result by using sql without looping through resultset? Thank you.

Comment: See examples of that thoughout the site: here's one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15209414/mysql-update-join or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806882/update-multiple-tables-in-mysql-using-left-join  If you're struggling implementing those with the above ask a different question, I'm positive you'll get the help.  We try and keep each question independent of others so each question/answer pair addresses specific needs.    By addressing a follow up here, it complicates the question and makes it less valuable to others.