# Matching data from two MySQL tables and inserting based on result

Tags: mysql, database

So I have two MySQL tables

"users" table includes id, listing_name and location

"wp_postmeta" table includes id, meta_key and meta_value

I want to insert meta_value from "wp_postmeta" into the location column in the "users" table, where both ID's match and meta_key's value is "address"

Example with the following values.

```
users TABLE
-----------
id: 1
listing_name: my listing
location: NULL

id: 2
listing_name: my listing 2
location: NULL
```

---

```
wp_postmeta TABLE
-----------
id: 1
meta_key: address
location: 12 Coding Avenue

id: 2
meta_key:address
location: 20 Python Drive
```

So afterwards my tables should look like:

```
users TABLE
-----------
id: 1
listing_name: my listing
location: 12 Coding Avenue

id: 2
listing_name: my listing 2
location: 20 Python Drive
```

---

```
wp_postmeta TABLE
-----------
id: 1
meta_key: address
location: 12 Coding Avenue

id: 2
meta_key:address
location: 20 Python Drive
```

I hope this is enough info.

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/806882/update-multiple-tables-in-mysql-using-left-join

Comment: Thanks, bni. Perfect!