# updating table with specific content from another table

Tags: php, mysqli

```
$updateDATA = $con->query("UPDATE table1 SET 
table1.content = table2.content, 
table1.draftid = 0
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.id = data_table.draftid 
WHERE table1.id=". $dataID) or die($con);
```

The above code is outputting this error:

`Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli could not be converted to string...`

I think its because `table2.content` is a string and its not quoted.  I've tried adding `'table2.content'` but that didn't work either..... can someone help please?

IF there is a better way of writing that query, I'm up for suggestions as well.

> **EDIT**

I updated my error reporting. `or die($con->error);`

Its now saying that the issue begins at LEFT JOIN ... telling me to check syntax.  Can you do a left join on an update query?  Am I formatting it correctly?  I've never done this before.

Comment: `or die($con->error);` , `$con` is an instance of mysqli and cannot be successfully converted into a string.. this may not fix the issue but it will get you to the next stage

Comment: that did get me further.  It is saying that the issue begins at LEFT JOIN.... can you do a left join on an update?  Am I formatting this correctly?  Never done it before

Comment: You know... I've never tried a join in an update, I don't think it's possible but I'll leave it for a mysql guru to step in :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for update with join is a bit different than the one of SELECT.

See here:

[UPDATE multiple tables in MySQL using LEFT JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/806882/update-multiple-tables-in-mysql-using-left-join)

Comment: I just had LEFT JOIN after SET instead of before.  Moved it and it worked perfectly.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
die()
```

expects string to be given as parameter but you pass $con which is mysqli object    instead. Write

```
die($con->error)
```